# What were Natasha's family's undercover names?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, black-widow-2021

I think we can assume that while (maybe arguably?) Natasha and Melina could pass as American names in 1995 Ohio, Alexei and Yelena definitely could not.

**Do we have any indication what the family's undercover names were?**

Comment: I’ve uncovered the spoilers. Anything that is revealed there is pretty much revealed in the title anyway.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot - I'm always of the opinion that anything that happens in the first two minutes of the film (and appears in the trailer) is unlikely to be an actual spoiler

Comment: Alex has been consistently one of the top 500 baby names in Ohio since records began, as have Helen and Helena. Since these are the Anglicised version of their names, it's possible that this is what they went by.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot:   I would argue that the fact they were undercover isn't surprising, but maybe that they were a (post) cold-war sleeper cell is.      It certainly never occured to me before that this is the reason Natasha's English is so good;  I just assumed she was supposed to be amazingly proficient.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** They either don't have any undercover names or just go by their anglicised versions of their "real" names. However, nothing definitive is given for them except Nat.

We know, at least, that Nat was still Nat (presumably short for Natasha) as at the start of the film we see a her riding her bike through the streets and a young girl calls out to her.

> **Girl:** Hey, Nat!
>
> <sub>*Black Widow*</sub>

We do also see Nat call Yelena "Yelena" when they are around the dinner table and before she knows they need to leave. This one's a bit unclear if it is her undercover name or not though. Nat should know better than to call her, her real name even at home but she may be relaxing a bit as they're all there with no guests. Similarly though Yelena is very young still and it was real to her, it's possible she didn't have another name but unclear. If Yelena isn't actually her undercover name it's probably just one of the anglicised versions so: Helena, Helen, Elena.

We should be able to work out Alexei's undercover name, if he has one, as we see a name badge a few times. However, it never really looks clear enough to me to make out the words. If he does have one it is likely just Alex though in keeping with Nat's "undercover" name as the anglicised version.

Melina is the only one we won't be able to work out from evidence in the film as there isn't anything that I can spot that can help us. However, if we keep in theme it's likely just the anglicised version, here probably still Melina. Note that in the comics Melina Vostokovna goes by her anglicised name of Melina Vostokoff: the first name doesn't change. It's possible the same is being done here. We see this in black and white in *All-New Official Handbook of the Marvel Universe A to Z: Update* Issue 2:

[image: Iron Maiden's page out of the comic above]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

No surname is known for their time undercover in America. However, once again we should be able to work it out from the name badge Alexei is wearing if we can get a clear image of it.

Comment: Doubling her strength = lifting 1000lbs ??

Comment: It said in the Marvel Black Widow Special that Yelena was too young to understand that these weren't her real parents and sister, so it's very unlikely that she had a fake name.

Comment: @Valorum They pretty much spell it out in the film too. I did mention that briefly in the answer.